# Is there $HeadURL$ equivalent for git?

Tags: git, svn

I am converting some svn files over and a few have the svn keyword `$HeadURL$`.

I am willing to use `$Format`, but don't see a placeholder that is equivalent.

Comment: Not really sure how that would work in git, since you technically checkout the working copy from your local clone. I suppose it could use the location of the branch your local branch is tracking, but that's just awkward; it would also be brittle since you don't need to track an upstream branch with a local branch.

Comment: Is it possible to include the tag associated with this file?